# HTML5 Tables fixed width/height without css?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to learn HTML 5, but not CSS yet, so trying to figure it out but so far no luck.
I got the Tables to draw sorta, but they are always changing size based on whats in them. I used to do this same thing in tables without issues so I guess either I forgot how or its diffrent in html5.
So I am trying to make a page layout take up 95% of both height and width and be centered on the browser window. I wanted 3 Rows and 3 Cols, with the header and footer(top and bottom) using all 3 Cols, and the center Left and Right side being around 100pixels wide, and the center midddle taken up the rest of the space.
The header I can get sized to about 80pixels no issue, but when I set a height to the center or bottom rows it seems to ignore them and just sizes them based on contents. I want the table fixed with scroll bars as needed. I dont know how to force it to set a size and leave it there without resizeing based on screen size or contents.
The code im using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>


<table height=100% width=100%" border=".5">
<tbody>
<tr height=90px width=100%>
<td colspan=3>Header/logo/etc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=100px>LeftSide Panel</td>
<td>Contents</td>
<td width=100px>RightSide Panel</td>
</tr>
<tr height=25px width=100%>
<td colspan=3>Footer</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what it looks like:
[screenshot of index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QILF0.png)
The center gets all smashed together without a fixed height and the center width dosent seem to set to 100px

Comment: Tables are not layout tools. If you want to do layout, learn CSS. If you want to learn just HTML, then focus on semantics.

Comment: And use [a validator](https://validator.nu/), you have numerous errors.

Comment: Just trying to learn html first css later, trying to not overload myself learning 2 sets of stuff at once.

Comment: You need to learn just a little bit of CSS when learning HTML anyway. At least the part that directly styles single elements - width and height included. You can leave the layout and other more advanced CSS concepts for later.

Comment: @RobertLee — Then, as I said, don’t try to learn layout. Otherwise you are trying to learn how to hack things which are not designed to do layout into doing layout … which is (a) wrong and (b) harder than learning how to do it right

Comment: What other options are then other then tables for something like this? I was going at that iframe but it needs a external source for each peice, trying to make it easier to edit content with php in as few files as possible ? I was told table would work fine so i was trying it. I hired someone to make some parts of it, but there code is unreadable, the css is 780 files over 40mb so I have no clue what nothing in it does. My idea was to make a basic backend system in php with a crude layout then hire someone to make it look good with css stuff.

Comment: @RobertLee - HTML is for document structure, CSS is for document presentation. What you have written out as a table is (give or take) equivalent to the following HTML structure: `<main></main> <nav></nav> <aside><aside> <header></header> <footer><footer>` if you then want to present that structure in any way - _including_ deciding where the individual elements of that structure are positioned - then CSS is your tool.

Comment: Hi, tables used to be the way to layout a webpage, but that was a couple of decades ago. Seriously, don’t start from there now. @Rounin makes a good point. There is lots about how to structure a document out there, but for why not tables read for example [link]https://thehistoryoftheweb.com/tables-layout-absurd/